# Can I make get_users() query global?

Tags: php, ajax, query

I have the following query

```
$args = [
        'meta_key' => 'mycred_default',
        'orderby'  => [ 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC' ],
        'order'    => 'desc',
        'number' => 10
];

$users = get_users( $args );
```

Can I make it global to access the parameters from an ajax function?

Comment: Hi, Giselle, welcome to WPSE. It is not clear what you mean exactly. Depending on what you want to achieve you could either define the parameters of the query as a global using `$GLOBALS['varname']`, or send the parameters in the ajax response or other strategy.

Comment: Hi @CelsoBessa, thank you! I wanna get the number because the idea is that it will be updated each time ajax is executed. I have been saving the parameters I need inside wp_localize_script(), can I access $GLOBALS['varname'] inside this function?

Comment: Global variables are usually the last choice when it comes to working with variables inside PHP - you could use either a function or a WordPress specific filter to store, update and retrieve the variable.

Comment: @QStudio hi! I'm sorry if this is too obvious, but please could you explain to me how a filter would work for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WordPress functions `apply_filters` and `add_filters` to store and retrieve data, like so:

```php
// The filter callback function.
function so_wp_380975_get_user_args( $array ) {
    
    // (maybe) modify $array.

    // for now, we just return the array
    return [
        'meta_key' => 'mycred_default',
        'orderby'  => [ 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC' ],
        'order'    => 'desc',
        'number' => 10
    ];

}
add_filter( 'get_user_args', 'so_wp_380975_get_user_args', 10, 1 );

// get the stored args from the filter
$args = apply_filters( 'get_user_args', [] );
```

Note that you can do a lot more, such as passing additional arguments to the filter to modify the args - or a default value, in case the filter returns nothing.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/